# How can I use MagicMock to mock an argument and test that my variable is set correctly?

Tags: python, magicmock

I have the following function `on_packet()`:

```
 class PacketContext:
    def __init__(self, capture_tstamp=None):
        self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp

 class Subparser(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.subparsers = {}
        self.context = PacketContext()
    
    def parse_er_data(self, bytes_data): 
       parent_file_name = os.path.basename(self.filename or '')
       ....

    def on_packet(self, packet):
        self.context.capture_tstamp = packet.capture_timestamp
        self.parse_er_data(packet.payload)
```

I want to used **MagicMock** to mock `packet`, to test that `self.context.capture_tstamp` is being set correctly. Here is my test function:

```
class TestTSE(Subparser, ExchangeTest):
    name = 'TSE'
    data_group = 'equities'
    default_subparser = TSEparser

    def __init__(self, *argv, **kwargs):
        Subparser.__init__(self)
        ExchangeTest.__init__(self, *argv, **kwargs)


    def test_receive_timestamp(self):
        packet = MagicMock(capture_timestamp=123456)
        self.on_packet(packet)
        assert self.context.capture_tstamp == 123456
```

But I know the `self.on_packet(packet)` is not correct, because `self` is referring to a TestTSE object.

I am getting the following error:

```
self = <tests.unit.exchanges.tse.test_quote_write.TestTSE testMethod=test_receive_timestamp>

    def test_receive_timestamp(self):
        """
        test receive_timestamp is passed down correctly from PacketContext to on_packet()
        """
        packet = MagicMock(capture_timestamp=123456)
>       self.on_packet(packet)

tests/unit/exchanges/tse/test_quote_write.py:86: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
exchanges/impl/tse/mixins.py:63: in on_packet
    self.parse_er_data(packet.payload)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <tests.unit.exchanges.tse.test_quote_write.TestTSE testMethod=test_receive_timestamp>, bytes_data = <MagicMock name='mock.payload' id='139811452485008'>

    def parse_er_data(self, bytes_data):
        """Maps current's file identifier with proper subparser's instance.
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        data: str
            Chunk of the data from file
        """
        # file being parsed
>       parent_file_name = os.path.basename(self.filename or '')
E       AttributeError: 'TestTSE' object has no attribute 'filename'

exchanges/impl/tse/mixins.py:51: AttributeError
```

Comment: Does your test work now? It looks like it should do.

Comment: Let me add the error- it is a bit confusing because I haven't added all the code to the above, but it will shed some light

Comment: I believe that `self` if pointing to the wrong thing!

Comment: Your `TestTSE` is missing a `filename` attribute, which must be set somewhere in the code you haven't shared for `Subparser`. Otherwise, this test should be working.

Comment: Ok, making a test subclass the class under test is tricky. Please update your question with the `__init__()` method of `Subparser`.

Comment: Err... take what out of the class? Now you have asked this question, don't change the basic premise.

Comment: @quamrana yes, I deleted the comment because I realised i can't take it out of the class, because that would break all of the logic

Comment: So the error is nothing to do with my test function? Because when I take out the test function everything else runs fine- so it must be something in my test function

Comment: I have added the test of the `TestTSE` intialization

Comment: Ok, you're adding stuff faster that I can read it. So `TestTSE` inherits from `TSESubparser`, but what about `Subparser`? Also can you add the `__init__()` method of `Subparser`?

Comment: `Subparser` doesn't inherit from any class. And I have added the `__init__()` for `Subparser`

Comment: How does a standalone `Subparser` work then? When does it get the `filename` attribute?

Comment: Sorry - amended now, `Subparser` is not a standalone, there was some confusing `import as`, but it is correct now!

Comment: No, I mean in a non-test scenario, when you just make a `Subparser` and then call `on_packet()`. This will fail without a `filename` attribute.

Comment: I don't quite understand, in a non-test scenario, on_packet() takes one argument `packet`- isn't this right?

Comment: And in my test, i am mocking (or trying to mock) this `packet` to be 123456

Comment: Please focus on the `filename` attribute. In a non-test scenario, when you have made a `Subparser` and then call `on_packet()` with a `packet` parameter. This will fail without a `filename` attribute. When is the `filename` attribute created?

Comment: @quamrana sorry again I missed out a crucial part of the code- I've added `parse_er_data(...)` now, which is called by on_packet() and which is causing the issue I believe? 
Is there anyway, I can stop this call? Because all I care about is testing `on_packet()`!

Comment: Well, you don't. When you say that you are testing the `on_packet()` method then you have to test the whole method. (Maybe you test different parts of the method in different tests) But the whole method must be run otherwise you aren't testing it. When is the `filename` attribute created?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not really looking to test the whole method, just that one line to be honest, as that is the line I added to the code- the other line existed before and was working! But if there is no way to test just that line then I'll think about something else- in any case, thanks for your time in reviewing, it is much appreciated!

Comment: You mentioned "you test different parts of the method in different tests", how can I isolate each part/line? - this is the issue here

Comment: I meant that one test, say, tests that the timestamp is updated and ignores any other behaviour and so on for other tests. But ultimately you need to know that `on_packet()` does all the things that are in there.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can just test solely the line ‘self.context.capture_tstamp = packet.capture_timestamp’ in on_packet()? Or is there simply no way to do it? - perhaps using a different mock method or mocking on_packet() somehow?

Comment: Put it in its own method and call it from on_packet.

Comment: I’m thinking if I encounter the same scenario in the future, separating each line into its own function wouldn’t seem ideal. Is it possible to patch self.parse_er_data() somehow so it doesn’t nothing, Instead of calling the actual parse_er_data() function?